# Advanced grouping in Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a bit of a brain twister, given data like this:

```
data = [('topic1', (['apples', 'oranges'], 0.14975108213820515)),
       ('topic2', (['oranges', 'raisins'], 0.14975108213820515)),
       ('topic3', (['grapes', 'raisins'], 0.14975108213820515)),
       ('topic4', (['trees', 'flowers'], 0.14975108213820515))]
```

I want to connect topics based on if at least one of the texts in the array (in the 1st element of the second element of the tuple) is in common. So in the above case:

```
topic1 is connected to topic2 
topic2 is connected to topic1 and topic3
topic3 is connected to topic2
topic4 is unconnected
```

Ideally, my output would look like:

```
output = [(topic1,topic2), 
         (topic1,topic2, topic3),
         (topic3, topic2),
         (topic4)]
```

So, given an input like `data` how could I get an output like `output`. I think itertools may be involved somehow, but I'm really stuck at this point.

Comment: Topic2 has elements in common with Topic1 and Topic3, but Topic1 and Topic3 have none and are only related because of Topic2. Does this matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An efficient way is to use `set`s.

```
>>> set1= set(['apples', 'oranges'])
>>> set2= set(['oranges', 'raisins'])
>>> print len(set1.intersection(set2))
1
```

So, basically:

- create a set for each topic's text
- for each topic, iterate each other topic and check the `len` of the intersection of their texts sets

---

```
topic_text_sets= {topic:set(text) for topic,(text,_) in data}
topic_related= {}
for topic1, text1 in topic_text_sets.iteritems():
    related= [topic2 for topic2, text2 in topic_text_sets.iteritems() if topic1!=topic2 and len(text1.intersection(text2))>0]
    print related
```

---

```
topic1 ['topic2']
topic3 ['topic2']
topic2 ['topic1', 'topic3']
topic4 []
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd create a dictionary with lists to capture the connections:

```
connections = {}
for topic, (conns, some_number) in data:
    for conn in conns:
        connections.setdefault(conn, set()).add(topic)
```

This maps connection values to sets of topics.

Now you can look up the inverse connections; just get the union of all connection value sets if the order doesn't matter:

```
output = [tuple(set().union(*(connections[c] for c in conns))) 
          for topic, (conns, some_number) in data]
```

Demo:

```
>>> data = [('topic1', (['apples', 'oranges'], 0.14975108213820515)),
...        ('topic2', (['oranges', 'raisins'], 0.14975108213820515)),
...        ('topic3', (['grapes', 'raisins'], 0.14975108213820515)),
...        ('topic4', (['trees', 'flowers'], 0.14975108213820515))]
>>> connections = {}
>>> for topic, (conns, some_number) in data:
...     for conn in conns:
...         connections.setdefault(conn, set()).add(topic)
... 
>>> [tuple(set().union(*(connections[c] for c in conns))) 
...               for topic, (conns, some_number) in data]
[('topic1', 'topic2'), ('topic1', 'topic3', 'topic2'), ('topic3', 'topic2'), ('topic4',)]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(_)
[('topic1', 'topic2'),
 ('topic1', 'topic3', 'topic2'),
 ('topic3', 'topic2'),
 ('topic4',)]
```

otherwise move `topic` to the front by removing it from the set first:

```
output = [(topic,) + tuple(set().union(*(connections[c] for c in conns)) - {topic}) 
          for topic, (conns, some_number) in data]

>>> [(topic,) + tuple(set().union(*(connections[c] for c in conns)) - {topic}) 
...               for topic, (conns, some_number) in data]
[('topic1', 'topic2'), ('topic2', 'topic1', 'topic3'), ('topic3', 'topic2'), ('topic4',)]
>>> pprint(_)
[('topic1', 'topic2'),
 ('topic2', 'topic1', 'topic3'),
 ('topic3', 'topic2'),
 ('topic4',)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple with two for loop:

```
>>> for i in range(len(data)):
...     x = set(data[i][1][0])
...     for j in range(len(data)):
...         if len(x & set(data[j][1][0]))>=1:
...             print data[j][0],             # for python 3 use print()
...     print
... 
topic1 topic2
topic1 topic2 topic3
topic2 topic3
topic4
```

Answer (score 0):

Break it up into subproblems.

First, you need to get all the different texts, maybe using a list comprehension (or set comprehension to avoid duplicates). Then you need to iterate through that, and for each text find each piece in `data` that has it as part of it. You shouldn't need to use itertools - that will probably overcomplicate it.